# Multicol tables with images

Tags: multicol

I would like to create a sheet with the packet with pictures multicol. Unfortunately I do not know how to do it.
I tried inserting tables that have the image on the right and left text.
But there is something that does not work.
To make it clear I did a test with MS Word.
Where mistake?
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{tabular}{l r}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{figure.pdf}
&
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please upload your pics directly in your post.

Comment: Try replacing the `r` column (where line breaking wont occur) with a `p` column, e.g. `p{4cm}` (where automatic line breaking will occur).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have edited your post a bit: Inserted the image and removed the opening. Note that the latter does not mean that we like to be rude, it's just our way to keep the Q&A comprehensive. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @musicman: One needs to have a certain rep (I guess it was 100) to upload images.

Comment: @Daniel ah ok, good to know...

Answer (score 3):

As Torbjørn T. pointed, `l`, `c` and `r` options for `tabular` columns definitions consider cell contents as a single line. If you want to define `paragraphs` option `p{par width}` should be used. It creates top aligned paragraphs. And if you load package `array` `m{par width}` for vertically centered paragraphs and `b{par width}` for bottom aligned ones can be used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{tabular}{m{3.5cm}m{.5\columnwidth}}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image.pdf}
&
\lipsum[2]
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This question was ask man, many times ... Problem is in type of last column, `r` (as was assumed in comments) assume that contents will be in one line and it adopt its width to the line. You need to change `r` to `p{<width>}` or (better} to `m{<width>}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{array}

    \begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0.4\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}
                   m{0.6\linewidth}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
&
\lipsum[2]
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0.6\linewidth}
                   m{0.4\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}@{}}
\lipsum[2]
&
\includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17\baselineskip]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}

\end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

For determination of column type and width I use packages `array` (for `m`) and `calc` (for calculation).

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:** For exploit full width of column I add `\noindent` before table and erase `-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth` from determination of the second column width.

**Edit:** The change order of columns with text and image is simple, in first table column you put a text and in second your image. To fit image ov table cell height, you need add option `height` into `\includegraphics`. But note: this will destroy original aspect ratio of image.  To show this, I replace existed MWE with new one, which show this (see corrected MWE and above picture).

Comment: I still have problems width SE webpage. When I submit my answer, it doesn't show answer submitted before me. It appears a while after then. Now I see, that my answer is almost duplicate to answer of Ignasi ... I'm very sorry for this. I haven't any intention to repeat it.

Comment: Try to empty the cache of your browser

Comment: Thanks for solutions. Now I try. Another two questions: 1) and if I'll want the image on the right in the table? 2) and if I'll want that the image was proportionate to the height of the text table? Excuse me for too many questions, but I'm involved to this latex...

Comment: For (i): interchange order of columns, for (ii) image is now proportional as define (with 4:3 size ratio).  If you doesn't bother with width/height ratio of original image, than you can simply add `height=<value>` and with this destroy it. How to determine `value` for height is another question ... the simplest way is to set it manually, more complicated is use `savebox` and then measure its height.